# Fn key shortcuts not working for paragraph styles

Tags: keynote

I was thrilled to discover I could create keyboard shortcuts for paragraph styles (see below, where I created one for F1).
[image]

However, it won't work (hitting F1 doesn't fix the paragraph style). I've made sure it's not a keyboard problem -- the function keys work fine for other things. What other kinds of troubleshooting might I try?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Have you tried to assign a different F-Key? Maybe F1 is used for something else already.

Comment: I figured it out, but unfortunately there's a feature limitation. I was trying to change the format of the presenter notes (hence the names I created for paragraph styles in the screenshots). Unfortunately paragraph styles can only be applied to text in the slides, not the notes. This is such a bummer and one of many reasons why I want to go back to Google Slides.